# How to do a filter in order to put at the end the results containing a null property?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with Angular in the frontend and I am trying to figure out how to do a filter in order to put at the end the results containing 2 properties in null. Could be one or the other property.

For example:

```
    <div ng-repeat="show in shows | filter:query | orderBy:'rating':true">
      <a href="/shows/{{show._id}}">
        <img ng-src="{{show.poster}}" width="100%"/>
      </a>
      <div>
        <a href="/shows/{{show._id}}">{{show.name}}</a>
        <p>
          Episodes: {{show.episodes.length}} <br>
          <span>Rating: {{show.rating}}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What I am doing in the HTML, is ordering by rating as you can see. The problem is that if the property `rating` comes `null`, then that element will be at the top of the results, and then the elements with the highest rating comes in the list just as I want.

This is the object I am receiving:

```
{
  "_id": 310243,
  "name": "Five Star Babies: Inside the Portland Hospital",
  "airsDayOfWeek": "Wednesday",
  "airsTime": "21:00",
  "firstAired": "2016-04-13T00:00:00.000Z",
  "network": "BBC Two",
  "overview": "An exclusive glimpse inside the UK's only private maternity hospital.\r\n",
  "rating": null, // THIS PROPERTY COMES NULL
  "ratingCount": 0,
  "status": "Continuing",
  "poster": "/someImage/path",
  "subscribers": []
}
```

The object comes from here:

```
$scope.shows = Show.query();
```

and that `$scope.shows` returns this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 73787,
    "name": "That '70s Show",
    "airsDayOfWeek": "Thursday",
    "airsTime": "8:00 PM",
    "firstAired": "1998-08-23T00:00:00.000Z",
    "network": "FOX (US)",
    "overview": "Set in the Wisconsin suburbs...",
    "rating": null, // PROPERTY NULL
    "ratingCount": 87,
    "status": "Ended"
    "poster": "/some/Img/Path"
  },
  {
    "_id": 35345,
    "name": "Friends",
    "airsDayOfWeek": "Thursday",
    "airsTime": "8:00 PM",
    "firstAired": "1998-08-23T00:00:00.000Z",
    "network": "FOX (US)",
    "overview": "New York TV Show...",
    "rating": 9.1,
    "ratingCount": 87,
    "status": "Ended"
    "poster": null // PROPERTY NULL
  }
]
```

That's the way the object comes, and those the 2 properties that I need to put at the end of the results in case they come `null`, `rating` or `poster`.

TL;DR:

OrderBy function which puts at the top of the results the elements with the highest ratings, and at the end the elements with `rating` or `poster` === `null`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Either adjust the data or use a custom filter

Comment: @charlietfl how to adjust the data is that is coming from an API ?

Comment: Can loop over the data when you receive it and change `null` to `0` so it sorts properly. Not uncommon to need to manipulate data to better suit your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own custom `orderBy` function which returns a value. For example:

```
$scope.order = function(show) {
    if (show.rating == null || show.poster == null) return 0;
    return show.rating;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="show in shows | filter:query | orderBy:order:true">
```

[Sample pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwVeEy?editors=1010).

Comment: mmm this is not doing anything

Comment: Interesting, let me take a look.

Comment: Well it definitely is working, but I've left out the reverse option. It should be `orderBy:order:true`, I'll edit my answer. Edit: added a sample pen as well.